# How to create/initialize custom objects in C++ the fastest way possible?

Tags: c++, performance, graph-theory

I have a function that creates a vector of Nodes and Edges from a vector of Profiles. Its working as intended, but this function is by far the slowest part of my full script. It takes around 150 milliseconds to run.

Machine(s):
Linux PC:

```
intel i7-12700k, 128 GB DDR4 3200 MHz RAM, Ubuntu LTS 20.04
```

Windows (WSL2) Laptop:

```
Ryzen 9 6900HX, 16 DB DDR5 RAM, Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (8 GB DDR5 RAM)
```

Both using gcc compiler and CMake and std=C++17

My source file that is the base of my entire program:

```cpp
#ifndef DEFINITIONS_H
#define DEFINITIONS_H

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <string_view>

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <chrono>

typedef std::string s;
typedef std::string_view stv;


struct Experience 
    {
        s from_date;
        s to_date;
        s position_title;
        float duration;
        s location;
        s institution_name;
        float salary;

        Experience(s from_date, s to_date, s position_title, float duration, s location, s institution_name, float salary)
            {
                this->from_date = from_date;
                this->to_date = to_date;
                this->position_title = position_title;
                this->duration = duration;
                this->location = location;
                this->institution_name = institution_name;
                this->salary = salary;
            }
        
        Experience()
            {
                this->from_date = "";
                this->to_date = "";
                this->position_title = "";
                this->duration = 0;
                this->location = "";
                this->institution_name = "";
                this->salary = 0;
            }
        
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Experience& e)
            {
                os << "from_date: " << e.from_date << std::endl;
                os << "to_date: " << e.to_date << std::endl;
                os << "position_title: " << e.position_title << std::endl;
                os << "duration: " << e.duration << std::endl;
                os << "location: " << e.location << std::endl;
                os << "institution_name: " << e.institution_name << std::endl;
                os << "salary: " << e.salary << std::endl;
                return os;
            }

    };
typedef std::vector<Experience> Experiences;

struct Profile
    {
        s linkedin_url;
        s name;
        Experiences experiences;
        std::vector<s> skills;

        Profile(s linkedin_url, s name, std::vector<s> skills, Experiences experiences)
            {
                this->linkedin_url = linkedin_url;
                this->name = name;
                this->skills = skills;
                this->experiences = experiences;
            }
        
        Profile()
            {
                this->linkedin_url = "";
                this->name = "";
                this->skills = {};
                this->experiences = {};
            }
        
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Profile& p)
            {
                os << "linkedin_url: " << p.linkedin_url << std::endl;
                os << "name: " << p.name << std::endl;
                os << "experiences: " << std::endl;
                for (auto e : p.experiences)
                    {
                        os << '\t' << e << std::endl;
                    }
                return os;
            }
    };

typedef std::vector<Profile> Profiles;

struct Node
    {
        s name;
        s position_title;
        s institution_name;
        s location;
        s industry;
        s linkedin_url;
        float duration;
        int company_size;
        float median_tenure;
        float salary;
        float headcount_growth;
        float current_experience_duration;

        Node(s t_name,s t_position_title, s t_institution_name, s t_location, s t_industry,s linkedin_url, float t_duration, float t_current_experience_duration, int t_company_size, float t_median_tenure, float t_salary, float t_headcount_growth )
            {
                this->name = t_name;
                this->position_title = t_position_title;
                this->institution_name = t_institution_name;
                this->location = t_location;
                this->industry = t_industry;
                this->linkedin_url = linkedin_url;
                this->duration = t_duration;
                this->current_experience_duration = t_current_experience_duration;
                this->company_size = t_company_size;
                this->median_tenure = t_median_tenure;
                this->salary = t_salary;
                this->headcount_growth = t_headcount_growth;
            }
        
        Node()
            {
                this->name = "";
                this->position_title = "";
                this->institution_name = "";
                this->location = "";
                this->industry = "";
                this->linkedin_url = "";
                this->duration = 0;
                this->current_experience_duration = 0;
                this->company_size = 0;
                this->median_tenure = 0;
                this->salary = 0;
                this->headcount_growth = 0;
            }

        bool operator==(const Node& other) const
            {
                if (this->name == other.name && this->position_title == other.position_title && this->institution_name == other.institution_name && this->location == other.location)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }
        
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Node& node)
            {
                os << "Name: " << node.name << std::endl;
                os << "Position Title: " << node.position_title << std::endl;
                os << "Institution Name: " << node.institution_name << std::endl;
                os << "Location: " << node.location << std::endl;
                os << "Industry: " << node.industry << std::endl;
                os << "Linkedin URL: " << node.linkedin_url << std::endl;
                os << "Duration: " << node.duration << std::endl;
                os << "Current Experience Duration "<< node.current_experience_duration << std::endl;
                os << "Company Size: " << node.company_size << std::endl;
                os << "Median Tenure: " << node.median_tenure << std::endl;
                os << "Salary: " << node.salary << std::endl;
                os << "Headcount Growth: " << node.headcount_growth << std::endl;
                return os;
            }
        
    };

typedef std::vector<Node> Nodes;


struct Edge
    {
        Node source;
        Node target;
        s linkedin_url;
        float duration;
        int company_size;
        float median_tenure;
        float salary;
        float headcount_growth;

        Edge(Node t_source, Node t_target)
            {
                
                this->source = t_source;
                this->target = t_target;
                this->linkedin_url = this->target.linkedin_url;
                this->duration = this->target.duration;
                this->company_size = this->target.company_size;
                this->median_tenure = this->target.median_tenure;
                this->salary = this->target.salary;
                this->headcount_growth = this->target.headcount_growth;
            }
        
        Edge()
            {
                this->source = Node();
                this->target = Node();
                this->linkedin_url = "";
                this->duration = 0;
                this->company_size = 0;
                this->median_tenure = 0;
                this->salary = 0;
                this->headcount_growth = 0;
            }
        
        bool operator==(const Edge& other) const
            {
                if (this->source == other.source && this->target == other.target)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }
        
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Edge& edge)
            {
                os << "Source: " << edge.source << std::endl;
                os << "Target: " << edge.target << std::endl;
                os << "Linkedin URL: " << edge.linkedin_url << std::endl;
                os << "Duration: " << edge.duration << std::endl;
                os << "Company Size: " << edge.company_size << std::endl;
                os << "Median Tenure: " << edge.median_tenure << std::endl;
                os << "Salary: " << edge.salary << std::endl;
                os << "Headcount Growth: " << edge.headcount_growth << std::endl;
                return os;
            }
    };


typedef std::vector<Edge> Edges;


struct Company
    {
        s name;
        s industry;
        float headcount_growth;
        float median_tenure;
        int company_size;

        Company(s name, s industry, float headcount_growth, float median_tenure, int company_size)
            {
                this->name = name;
                this->industry = industry;
                this->headcount_growth = headcount_growth;
                this->median_tenure = median_tenure;
                this->company_size = company_size;
            }
        
        Company()
            {
                this->name = "";
                this->industry = "";
                this->headcount_growth = 0;
                this->median_tenure = 0;
                this->company_size = 0;
            }
        
        bool operator==(const Company& other) const
            {
                if (this->name == other.name)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                else
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
            }
        
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Company& company)
            {
                os << "Name: " << company.name << std::endl;
                os << "Industry: " << company.industry << std::endl;
                os << "Headcount Growth: " << company.headcount_growth << std::endl;
                os << "Median Tenure: " << company.median_tenure << std::endl;
                os << "Company Size: " << company.company_size << std::endl;
                return os;
            }

    };

typedef std::vector<Company> Companies;

#endif // DEFINITIONS_H
```

The profiles.h source file (have not included irrelevant code):

```cpp
#ifndef PROFILES_H
#define PROFILES_H

#include "definitions.h"

std::pair<Nodes,Edges> create_edges_and_nodes_from_profiles(Profiles & profiles, Companies & companies );

#endif // PROFILES_H
```

The profiles.cpp file:

```cpp
std::pair<Nodes,Edges> create_edges_and_nodes_from_profiles(Profiles & profiles, Companies & companies)
    {
        using namespace std::literals;

        Nodes nodes;
        Edges edges;
        nodes.reserve(40'000);
        edges.reserve(40'000);

        bool use_profile;


        std::unordered_map<s,float> company_name_median_tenure_map;
        std::unordered_map<s,float> company_name_headcount_growth_map;
        std::unordered_map<s,int> company_name_company_size_map;
        std::unordered_map<s,s> company_name_industry_map;

        float current_duration;
        float t_company_size, t_median_tenure, t_headcount_growth, t_duration, t_salary;
        s t_name, t_position_title, t_location, t_institution_name, t_industry;

        

        #ifdef MONITOR
            auto before_map_createion = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        #endif  

        for (Company & company : companies)
            {
                
                company_name_median_tenure_map[company.name] = company.median_tenure;
                company_name_headcount_growth_map[company.name] = company.headcount_growth;
                company_name_company_size_map[company.name] = company.company_size;
                company_name_industry_map[company.name] = company.industry;

            }
        
        #ifdef MONITOR
            auto after_map_creation = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

            auto temp = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(after_map_creation-before_map_createion).count();

            std::cout<<temp<<std::endl;
        #endif

        for (Profile & profile : profiles)
            {
                Nodes nodes_temp;
                nodes_temp.reserve(profile.experiences.size());
                current_duration = 0.0;
                use_profile = false;


                for (Experience & experience : profile.experiences)
                    {
                        
                        stv location = stv(experience.location);
                        
                        if (location.compare(""sv)!=0)
                            {
                                
                                //if (location.find("United Kingdom"sv)!=stv::npos)
                                    
                                t_name = profile.name;
                                t_position_title = experience.position_title;
                                t_location = experience.location;

                                
                                t_duration = experience.duration;
                                
                                
                                t_institution_name = experience.institution_name;
                                
                                t_company_size = company_name_company_size_map[t_institution_name];
                                t_median_tenure = company_name_median_tenure_map[t_institution_name];
                                t_headcount_growth = company_name_headcount_growth_map[t_institution_name];

                                
                                t_salary = experience.salary;


                                t_industry = company_name_industry_map[t_institution_name];
                                
                                Node node_obj = Node(std::move(t_name),
                                    std::move(t_position_title),
                                        std::move(t_institution_name),
                                            std::move(t_location),
                                                std::move(t_industry),
                                                    profile.linkedin_url,
                                                        t_duration,
                                                            current_duration,
                                                                t_company_size,
                                                                    t_median_tenure,
                                                                        t_salary,
                                                                            t_headcount_growth);
                                                        
                                
                                nodes_temp.push_back(std::move(node_obj));
                                
                                current_duration += t_duration;
                                    
                            }
                        
                    }
                
                for (Node & node : nodes_temp)
                    {
                        if (node.location.compare(""sv)!=0)
                        {
                            use_profile = true;
                            break;
                        }
                            
                    }
                
                if (!use_profile)
                    continue;
                
                current_duration = 0.0;

                for (Nodes::reverse_iterator rit=nodes_temp.rbegin();rit!=nodes_temp.rend();++rit)
                    {
                        rit->current_experience_duration = current_duration;
                        current_duration += rit->duration;
                    }
                
                if (nodes_temp.size()>1)
                    {
                        for (int i=0;i<nodes_temp.size()-1;i++)
                            {
                                //Edge edge = Edge(&nodes_temp[i+1],&nodes_temp[i]);
                                edges.emplace_back(std::move(nodes_temp[i+1]),std::move(nodes_temp[i]));

                            }
                    }
                
                for (auto & node : nodes_temp)
                    {
                        nodes.push_back(std::move(node));
                    }
            }

        return std::make_pair(std::move(nodes),std::move(edges));
    }
```

Now in my main driver:

```cpp
#include "definitions.h"
#include "profiles.h"


int main()
  {
     // not shown (but assume this works and created the profile objects as shown in definitions.h)
     Profiles profiles = get_profiles(coll_profiles);
    // Make the same assumption as before 
     Companies companies = get_companies(coll_companies);

      #ifdef MONITOR
            
          auto before_creating_edges_and_nodes =  std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
            
      #endif

        
        
      // Create nodes and edges from profiles and companies
      auto[nodes, edges] =  create_edges_and_nodes_from_profiles(profiles,companies);

      #ifdef MONITOR
          auto after_creating_edges_and_nodes =  std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
          auto time_creating_edges_and_nodes = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(after_creating_edges_and_nodes - before_creating_edges_and_nodes).count();

            
      #endif
      // lots of functions using Nodes and Edges 
      //...
      //...
      return 0;
  }
```

**Note that I am not an expert in C++**. The code shown above works but it takes a significant amount of time (~150 milliseconds). The rest of the script combined (around 15 functions) takes less than 100 milliseconds.

My question is basically, how do I restructure the data and/or the initialization of the objects so that it is as fast as possible.

The reason I am asking is because, I found it impossible to find how to do this on Google. It could be because I don't know the right terminology.

Comment: Better place to ask such questions is https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I did post there. Its very inactive.  It got like 1 view per hour. I don't think I am breaking any rules by deleting the post there and moving it here

Comment: Do you have an address book where you store first names of your contacts and another one where you store last names and another one where you store phone numbers and another one where you store addresses? No? Why do you have a zillion `company_name_<whatever>` maps then?

Comment: @n.m.willseey'allonReddit Unfortunately no. The company information is initialised from a mongodb collection. The zillion company name maps take around 2 milliseconds to create. So this is not the bottleneck

Comment: So if you know which parts of your code are not the bottleneck, why are you showing them?

Comment: @n.m.willseey'allonReddit The create_edges_and_nodes_from_profiles function is the bottleneck. I know what the bottleneck it but I have no clue where/how to even go about fixing this. Specifically the problem seems to be that my Node and Edge data structure is too inefficient.

Comment: Unlearn to to typedef's (or usings) just to safe yourself a bit of typing. It is bad practice because it makes code unreadable for anyone else (including your future you). And read up on [class initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor). So all in all before you want to go fast (and you have a proven performance issue) it is important to go "well".

Comment: @PepijnKramer you are right. I felt typedef(ing) std::string to s is perhaps too egregious. I think typedef(ing) std::vector<Edge> as Edges is ok though

Comment: Well maybe it is, but you can also to that with a getter function : `const auto& Edges() const noexcept { return m_edges; }`. Type aliasing is used to show some kind of semantic meaning (altough it is even better to make strong types then). The more you use standard notation the easier it is to read for everybody. The goal is not to save a bit of time the first time you type your code, trust me you (or others) will spent more time on reading (debugging/refactoring) code later

Comment: @PepijnKramer Now that I think about it, you are right.

Comment: I don't know how much of a difference it will make, but I would replace the four `company_name_*_map` objects with a single `unordered_map<std::string, CompanyInfo> company_info_map;` (where `CompanyInfo` is a struct or class that holds the four different attributes you are storing) .... that way you only have to do one lookup per iteration of the loop instead of four, and your data will have better cache-locality.

Comment: How come you don't directly initialize your member variables in your `Experience` constructor from the parameters?  (Given that you are trying to improve performance.)  Likewise for all other constructors.

Comment: @Eljay Not sure whether I understand. Do you mean that I should initilize the Nodes and Edges while initializing the experiences/ profiles objects?

Comment: Do you know how to initialize member variables in a constructor in C++?

Comment: @Eljay you mean the member initializer lists?

Comment: Use a profiler, it will show you problematic lines. But before doing that, look at your huge `Node` struct. Does it make sense to pass it around *by value*? Every `Edge` has a pair of copies of those, does it make any sense? Do you need to pass strings by value? Vectors of strings?

Comment: Correct, member variables get initialized in the member initialization lists.  For example, a `float` default initialization is uninitialized (not in a valid state).  A `string` default initialization is empty string.  The code default initializes the string, only to *assign* another string to it in the body of the constructor.  It'd be far better (performant) to initialize it in the member initialization list and `std::move` the parameter string into the member variable string.  Kill two performance issues with one stone.

Comment: @n.m.willseey'allonReddit  I tried to use callgrind profiler. But I couldn't make sense of it. Instead i created Monitioring instrumentation (#ifdef MONITOR) to measure the raw latency for each single task. You are right about the problem of the Huge Node struct. That was my first suspision. I tried making the Edge have Node pointers but kept getting segmentation faults. I couldn't find where I we getting segmentation faults either (I was using valgrind). 

How would you define the Nodes and Edges here?

Comment: You find segfaults and the like with a debugger like gdb. I would define an edge as a pair of pointers or indices to node (possibly shared_ptr depending on how nodes are stored)

Comment: @Eljay After using initialization list, the latency did reduce from (64 milliseconds to 48 miliseconds averaged over 20 runs). Thanks. It was reduced from 150 milliseconds to 64 miliseconds after not looking up 4 seperate uorderderd maps

Comment: @n.m.willseey'allonReddit Thanks. right now Nodes = std::vector<Node>. If I want to use shared pointers, i would need it to be  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Node>>?

Comment: Yes basically. Or you can just use indices into `vector<Node>`.

Comment: @n.m.willseey'allonReddit Actually thats a brilliant plan. After I create the Nodes and Edges, they basically keep their index in the vector. Any filtering of Nodes and Edges can still be handelled straightforwardly. Instead of Storing the Large Node objects in Edges, you just store an size_t variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
    std::unordered_map<s,float> company_name_median_tenure_map;
    std::unordered_map<s,float> company_name_headcount_growth_map;
    std::unordered_map<s,int> company_name_company_size_map;
    std::unordered_map<s,s> company_name_industry_map;
```

with

```
struct company_data
{
float tenure;
float growth;
int size
std:string industry;      // this should be an index into a table of industry names
};

std::unordered_map<std::string,company_data>  company_map;
```

Comment: This significantly reduced the latency of the function from ~150 milliseconds to ~64 milliseconds (averaged over 20 runs). Why is doing just one lookup vs 4 lookups per iterations so impactful? In my experience C++ unorded_map lookups are extremely cheap

Comment: How many profiles and companies are you constructing for your timing test?  I have copied your code into a github repo ( https://github.com/JamesBremner/so76550312 ) and when I run it with 10,000 companies and 10,000 profiles default constructed it takes less than a millisecond.

Comment: Interesting. I have around 20,000 profiles and 10,000 companies. I git cloned your repo and took a look into it. I initially also got results of less than a milisecond. This is because you are not hitting the inner loop as the there are no expriences. Also because the location string in default inatialized Experience is empty, the inner loop is not run. I have sent a PR on github with my modifications

Comment: I merged your changes to definitions.h.  It now takes 83 msecs - in agreement with your results.

Comment: I have implemented and tested several optimizations as described in https://github.com/JamesBremner/so76550312/issues/2

Comment: I have re-implemented your code using my best understanding of OOD principles.  It now constructs a graph of 100,000 nodes and 90,000 edges in 5 millisecs